# Why did my scuplting mesh randomly "shatter"?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

This is how my mesh looks right now, it's completely "shattered" as in missing a bunch of triangles. Why did this occur and how do I fix it? I already used up all my "undos" with ctrl+z so I'm stuck with this now. I have no idea what I did to cause this, it happened earlier to another part but for some reason it randomly disappeared and fixed itself when I go into object mode and then back into scuplting mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to object mode and then back into scuplting mode fixes the problem temporarily. but it periodically comes back. Once I merge everything and remesh the problem never happens again. I still have no clue why it sometimes happen and sometimes doesn't.